# Edit Form Delete's a record from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I Have a nested form that works pretty well in saving content to the database. The only problem is that when I click edit, the "grand-child" field is deleted from the database and thus I have to re-enter everything on that field. The normal behavior is on editing the previous content should be present.

I am using `gem cocoon` for nested forms `simple_forms` for my forms and `ckeditor` for richtext editing.

This is the server log when I click edit: notice: `SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "responses" WHERE "responses"."id" = $1  [["id", 53]]` which happens every time I click edit on any entry in the exam model. Also notice that the question is selected but not deleted. Very strange.

```
    Started GET "/exams/24/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-09 16:59:40 +0300
Processing by ExamsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"24"}
  Exam Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "exams".* FROM "exams" WHERE "exams"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 24]]
  Question Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."exam_id" = $1  [["exam_id", 24]]
  Response Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "responses".* FROM "responses" WHERE "responses"."question_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["question_id", 44]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "responses" WHERE "responses"."id" = $1  [["id", 53]]
   (15.3ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered exams/_response_fields.html.haml (2.4ms)
  Rendered exams/_response_fields.html.haml (2.1ms)
  Rendered exams/_question_fields.html.haml (32.6ms)
  Rendered exams/_response_fields.html.haml (0.7ms)
  Rendered exams/_response_fields.html.haml (0.6ms)
  Rendered exams/_question_fields.html.haml (8.1ms)
```

Exam model `exam.rb`

```
belongs_to :unit

has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy

has_many :answers, :through => :questions

accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
```

Quesions model

```
belongs_to :exam

has_one :response, :dependent => :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :response
```

Response model

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :question
end
```

`_form.html.haml` partial

```
    = simple_form_for @exam do |f|
      - if @exam.errors.any?
        #error_explanation
          %h2= "#{pluralize(@exam.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this exam from being saved:"
          %ul
            - @exam.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
              %li= msg

      .field
        = f.label :Exam_Title
        = f.text_field :title , size: 100
      .field
        = f.label :date
        = f.datetime_select :date

      .field
        = f.simple_fields_for :questions do |question|
          = render "question_fields", f: question
        .links
          = link_to_add_association 'Add Question', f, :questions

      .field
        =f.label :unit
        =f.select :unit_id, Unit.all.map { |u| [u.name, u.id]}


      .actions
        = f.submit 'Save'
```

`_questions.html.haml` partial

```
    .nested-fields
    %br/
    = f.label :question, "Question"
    = link_to_remove_association "Remove Question", f
    %br/
    = f.cktext_area :question, :cols => 30, :ckeditor => {:uiColor => '#f7931e', :toolbar => 'mini'}
    %br/
    .link
        = link_to_add_association 'Add Answer', f, :response


    = f.fields_for :response do |answer|
        =render "response_fields", f: answer
```

`_responses.html.haml` partial

```
.nested-fields
%br/
= f.label :response, "Answer"
= link_to_remove_association "Remove Answer", f
= f.cktext_area :answer, :cols => 10, :ckeditor => {:uiColor => '#f7931e', :toolbar => 'mini'}
```

**Update**

exam edit page just renders the form. `edit.html.haml`

```
 %h1 Editing exam

= render 'form'

= link_to 'Show', @exam
\|
= link_to 'Back', exams_path
```

Parameters sent during save:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OvzRdRYT8zeCz6pTxcJT4o3maLb1TFw7iYxytZmnVkT7ZAG/maxeZLIoizlc8QMIMA4IrZoufh17Xkmt0NvG3A==", "exam"=>{"title"=>"Bla bla bla", "date(1i)"=>"2015", "date(2i)"=>"11", "date(3i)"=>"9", "date(4i)"=>"12", "date(5i)"=>"05", "questions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "question"=>"<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\" style=\"width: 500px;\">\r\n\t<tbody>\r\n\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t<td>blalal</td>\r\n\t\t\t<td>nalndjksl</td>\r\n\t\t</tr>\r\n\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t<td>sdfjsdljfl</td>\r\n\t\t\t<td>kjfskldjfksl</td>\r\n\t\t</tr>\r\n\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t<td>kdfjkdjf</td>\r\n\t\t\t<td>gldjkgldfj</td>\r\n\t\t</tr>\r\n\t</tbody>\r\n</table>\r\n\r\n<p>htkathiuerwehjr uyewuyrhjewhr ;aueryaueh rw erkjwherw</p>\r\n", "response_attributes"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "answer"=>"<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"/uploads/ckeditor/pictures/1/content_hand_wrinting.gif\" style=\"width: 721px; height: 370px;\" /></p>\r\n"}, "id"=>"44"}}, "unit_id"=>"4"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"24"}
```

parameters sent during edit `Parameters: {"id"=>"24"}`

server log on loading the edit page

```
  Exam Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "exams".* FROM "exams" WHERE "exams"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 24]]
  Question Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."exam_id" = $1  [["exam_id", 24]]
  Response Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "responses".* FROM "responses" WHERE "responses"."question_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["question_id", 44]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "responses" WHERE "responses"."id" = $1  [["id", 59]]
   (12.1ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered exams/_response_fields.html.haml (2.6ms)
  Rendered exams/_response_fields.html.haml (2.3ms)
  Rendered exams/_question_fields.html.haml (44.3ms)
  Rendered exams/_response_fields.html.haml (0.7ms)
  Rendered exams/_response_fields.html.haml (0.6ms)
  Rendered exams/_question_fields.html.haml (10.1ms)
```

Update! `exam_controller.rb`

```
def exam_params
  params.require(:exam).permit(:title, :attachment, :date, :unit_id, 
    questions_attributes:[ :id, :question, :exam_id,  :_destroy,
    response_attributes:[:id, :answer, :question_id, :_destroy]]
    # responses:[:id, :response, :question_id, :_destroy]]
    )
end

def new
@exam = Exam.new
  1.times do
    @exam.questions.build.build_response
  end
```

end

# GET /exams/1/edit
  def edit
  end

Thanks for for your help!

Comment: Some general advice:  Have a look at what's coming through in params: in particular, anything like `params[exam][question_ids]` or similar: this could be wiping the questions.    If what's in params looks right, then your code which processes params is wiping the questions.  if params doesn't look right, then fix the form.

Comment: We probably need a look at `ExamsController#edit`

Comment: @MaxWilliams the parameters look right. And it's the answers  being wiped not thequestions.

Comment: @Kristján I've added it on the update. But it just renders the form I added earlier.

Comment: @Denn I meant `edit` in your controller, not the template

Comment: @Kristján My edit controller has no code. It's on the update, Thanks.

Comment: Well, something is deleting during edit according to your logs. Start commenting things out and track down that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got it!!**

The problem was here `_questions.html.haml`

```
.nested-fields
%br/
= f.label :question, "Question"
= link_to_remove_association "Remove Question", f
%br/
= f.cktext_area :question, :cols => 30, :ckeditor => {:uiColor => '#f7931e', :toolbar => 'mini'}
%br/
.link
    = link_to_add_association 'Add Answer', f, :response


= f.fields_for :response do |answer|
    =render "response_fields", f: answer
```

The line `= link_to_add_association 'Add Answer', f, :response` was causing the problem. it forces the previous answer to be removed so as to add a new one as opposed to editing the old one as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `:force_non_association_create => true` on every `link_to_add_association`.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031796/rails-deletes-record-on-edit-and-not-submit/37032309#37032309) for more information!

Comment: If you feel that this question is a duplicate, please flag it as such.  Please don't post links to other Stack Overflow answers.

Comment: @JAL thanks for the suggestion - but I don't think this question is a duplicate, I think it lacks information on the resolution and I merely posted a possible solution which relates to one of my questions.

Comment: Please note that in this question a `Response` is a `has_one` relation, and rails is so smart that when you create a new element on a `has_one`, the previous is deleted. So in that case (only) it makes sense to use the `force_non_association_create` flag. However, not sure what happens when you save multiple responses. Secondly, UX wise, if there already is a response, the user can just edit it. But there is no need to suggest the `force_non_association_create` on each association.