# Rails deletes record on edit and not submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form, cocoon-gem

Having the following associations:

`Workout has_many workout_sets through ...`

`workout_set has_many workout_steps through ...`

When editing an object I'm experiencing the following issue:

1) go to `/model/:id/edit`

2) checking the db, once the page loads the top level attributes (the non-nested ones) are deleted from the db once the page loads, but the select marks as selected the correct values, as if in the moment of the load the data was correct.

3) leaving the page without saving (returning to `/model/:id`) does the following:

- 3.1) don't update the object, due to no form is submitted.
- 3.2) leave me with a model without it's primary properties, while the deepest nested attributes remain unchanged.

I'm using [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/) and [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) to handle nested models. Is it something on Rails I'm missing out?

P.S: I can provide code if needed.

Comment: So far have found a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610981/edit-form-deletes-a-record-from-the-database), but the solution is unclear.

Comment: Yes, please provide code. Especially the associations definition. It is unclear to me what is deleted. "top-level attributes" are deleted? So you mean the attributes from workout (which is the top element?) are cleared?

Comment: Hi @nathanvda ! already fixed it. With top level attributes I meant the ones that are not nested. For example a workout has `title`, `description` (first/top level) ... and `workout_sets`, this last one is an array of objects. But again, see the answer below.

Comment: How does creating a new element on an association have an effect on the parent element? That is not possible using just standard rails associations, your answer seems to imply that people should never be using the `force_non_association_create` which is imho wrong (while it works for simple associations, it does not use of the predefined settings/scopes etc on the association). I am trying to find out what you are doing differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record:

The solution is as simple as:

`:force_non_association_create => true` on each `link_to_add_association`. For more information check [this](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#force_non_association_create)